# Actual Count Of Objects Incorrect After Deletion Of Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Two days ago I deleted a bucket that contained a backup of all log files for a site. It contained about 30,000 tiny files and about 275 MB of space.

I noticed in the Monitoring panel of the site that the file count is exactly the same. Decided to wait a couple of days and it still has not changed.

The bucket uses standard storage class, multi-region location, and has no lifecycle rules with uniform permissions.

I can verify that the bucket is gone in the UI as well as using the ls command in cloud shell.

[Cloud Storage Object Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75NHr.png)

[Cloud Storage Object Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvwMC.png)

Comment: Does the bucket have versioning enabled? If so, deleting files leaves old versions around, which consume space.

Comment: Where is that policy set?  I have looked through the UI for storage and don't see any mention of versioning.

Comment: The storage UI doesn't show versioning in the config section. You can check using:
`gsutil ls -Lb gs://your-bucket'

You're looking for the line:
Versioning enabled:             True

Comment: Definitively interesting to see. Unfortunately I checked and this versioning is disabled across all my buckets. And the bucket in question no longer exists.

Comment: If you use a CDN with cache, you might need to invalidate cache in order to refresh object count.

Answer (score 3):

The count of objects in the Monitoring panel reconciled about two days later.

Looks like the change ended up being retroactive, meaning the charts in the past were re-written to reflect the objects being deleted.

Comment: thank you for coming back and answering this once you had a solution.